# What is the name of this scifi movie with an AI robot on another planet gone rogue

Tags: story-identification, hard-sci-fi

It's been 10 or 20 years since I've seen this science fiction movie, it's bugging me I can't find it.  I'll describe the plot the best I can.

A number of crewmen board a manned space mission to another planet for science.  They bring a 4 legged robot with them that has character, because one of the crew questions its sentience, and the robot slashes his neck with a red marker in a show of strength.

The crew gets to the planet but systems fail and they crash land, they are saved by airbags to cushion their fall, but then they roll down a valley and crash a second time into a ravine, killing many crew and seriously wounding others.

As the crew assess damage, one crew-member uses a tricorder to assess he has multiple broken ribs and can't go on, and he insists the others leave him there to die.  The AI robot is fully functional and goes off to get help.

On the journey, the remaining crew fight each other over petty squabbles and damage their life support equipment.  They decide to harvest the AI robot for parts to save the crew, but the AI robot learns of their plan and harms them to escape.

Somehow the AI robot turned on its own "war games mode" in order to preserve its own life, and then proceeds to attack the crew, killing most of them off.  At one point the robot shows incredible resourcefulness by spawning a helicopter like device for overhead surveillance.

One remaining crew member was able to outsmart the AI robot by faking it out, making him think he was inside a cave when in fact he was hidden to deal the final death blow.

The final crew member was without assistance and supplies so he fell victim  to the elements and unfortunate situations, and the final scene it was revealed the planet contained these kind of glow-bugs like life forms, and the movie ended there with the alien bugs consuming the remains of the last crew member.

Can anyone name that movie?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That's AMEE from 'Red Planet'

Here are some screen grabs showing demo where AMEE is handed a marker and put in Military Mode.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: YES!!! Thank you so much!  It's interesting how this ancient movie has been lodged in my head for the last 17 years and jumps out when I start thinking about Tri-corder medical technology.  Our brains don't have a delete button, you encode all these movies in, they're there forever.

Comment: There's always at least one typo jpmc26 - Many tanks for pointing it out for me.